# Redirecting Spring Boot to Template Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im integrating Payment Gateway with Spring Boot - Thymeleaf

I have sample application provided by payment gateway provide which is JSP based as like below

```
response.jsp

<%@ page language="java" session="true" %>
<%

String    tranid=request.getParameter("tranid");
String result=request.getParameter("result");
out.println("REDIRECT=https://www.example.com/jsp/result.jsp?tranid="+tranid);

%>
```

Payment gateway redirects the call (after processing the payment) to response.jsp. Inside response.jsp they are redirecting to another page to show the result.

The same thing in Spring Boot

Controller class (which is given to provide to redirect)

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/response")
public String responseHandlerSuccess(ServletRequest request,  Model model) {
return "redirect:https://www.example.com/success?tranid="+tranid;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showProduct(@RequestParam Map<String,String> response, ModelMap response){
System.out.println("Success Received  ...");
return "success" // Success Template
}
```

Im able to see the message "

> Sucess Received ...

" but the page is not re-directed to success template. So the payment gateway throws error page. How to make it work?

Comment: It's not because you return a String, not a page.

Comment: sucess is my template name. It should resolve to the template?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the files Spring can resolve. You can use different type of Resolver : ViewBased Resolver to resolve templates, UrlBased Resolver to resolve template and redirection, etc..
To set your resolver you need to implement in via XML or via some configurations class.

Here is an example of Resolver:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMvc
@ComponentScan("The package you want spring to scan")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("Your View Directory, in my case it was '/WEB-INF/Views/'");
        resolver.setSuffix("Your Views'extention, .jsp for example");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

To finish the configuration I use a class which extend AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer. You need to override 3 methods:

```
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses();
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses();
protected String[] getServletMappings();
```

The second one is where you actually use the View resolver. In my case I just override it like this :

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
    return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
}
```

If you follow this lead it shall normally work, don't hesitate if you need more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Spring Boot** , and so no need to do such xml configs.

Add given line to your application.properties file

```
#Page settings
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /view/html/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```